# Dynamic xpath handling

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below is my *xpath*

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/div/a/div")).click();
```

In above code value of div[6] is keep changing.
Sometimes it will

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div/a/div")).click();`
 or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/a/div")).click();
```

Please provide solution.

Comment: No body other than you knows, until you explain more about the context

Comment: Share your html code with us.

Comment: Please add html code

Answer (score 0):

We faced this issue with dynamic page content making XPath identification basically useless.  We took the decision to make sure everything that needed to be identified in a test would have an id set.  So:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div/a/div")).click();
```

becomes:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myDivId")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div 'id' or 'class' instead of div[6].

like:

```
/html/body/div[@id='div_id']/div/a/div
```

(or)

```
/html/body/div[@class='div_className']/div/a/div
```